# Unknown type name Error in C program

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am working on C program.i got a compiler error of unknown type name even if the type is declared in .h(header file). Given Below declaration and definition for type name extract from the longer code for the sake of simplicity?

```
               //DECLARATION

                typedef  int    DiscrValue,      /* discrete attribute value (0 = ?) */
                        Attribute;          /* attribute number, 1..MaxAtt */

                typedef  union _attribute_value
                     {
                        ContValue   _cont_val;
                        DiscrValue  _discr_val;
                     }
                     AttValue, *DataRec;

                String      Target,     /* name of dependent att */
                            *AttName,   /* att names */
                            **AttValName;   /* att value names */

                //DIFINITION 

                Attribute   ClassAtt=0, /* attribute to use as class */
                            LabelAtt=0, /* attribute containing case label */
                            CWtAtt=0;   /* attribute containing case weight */

                DataRec *Case;      /* data items */

                String      Target,     /* name of dependent att */
                            *AttName,   /* att names */
                            **AttValName;   /* att value names */
```

with above given declaration and definition, when I try to compile the program i got errors.

```
                            [ERROR]Unknown type name  'Attribute'
                           [ERROR]Unknown type name  'DataRec'
                           [ERROR]Unknown type name  'String'
```

Any help is very much appreciated

```
**EDIT**

    As I requested i put the header file (defns.h) and the source file(global.c)  Here below 

      **define.h**

    #define  RELEASE    "2.08"

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    #include <float.h>

    #ifdef   WIN64
    #define  WIN32
    #endif

    #define  SMP
    #define  MAXCPU     8
    #if defined WIN32 || defined _CONSOLE
    //-----------------------------------
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <process.h>

    #define  Thread             HANDLE
    #define  ThreadFn           void *
    #define  BeginThread(t,f,a)     t = (Thread) _beginthreadex(NULL, 0,\
                            (ThreadFn) (*f),\
                            (PVOID) a, 0, NULL)
    #define  EndThread          _endthreadex(1)
    #define  ThreadReturn           return(0)
    #define  JoinThread(t)          {WaitForSingleObject(t, INFINITE);\
                         CloseHandle(t);}

    #define  Flag               HANDLE
    #define  MakeFlag(f,n)          f = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, n, NULL)
    #define  DestroyFlag(f)         CloseHandle(f)
    #define  RaiseFlag(f)           ReleaseSemaphore(f, 1, NULL)
    #define  WaitForFlag(f)         WaitForSingleObject(f, INFINITE)

    #define  Mutex              HANDLE
    #define  MakeMutex(m)           m = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL)
    #define  DestroyMutex(m)        CloseHandle(m)
    #define  LockMutex(m)           WaitForSingleObject(m, INFINITE)
    #define  UnlockMutex(m)         ReleaseMutex(m)
    //-----------------------------------
    #else
    //-----------------------------------
    #include <pthread.h>
    #include <semaphore.h>
    #include <sys/unistd.h>

    #ifndef _SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF
    #define _SC_NPROCESSORS_CONF _SC_NPROC_CONF
    #endif

    #define  Thread             pthread_t
    #define  ThreadFn           void *
    #define  BeginThread(t,f,a)     pthread_create(&t, NULL, f, (void *) a)
    #define  EndThread          pthread_exit(NULL)
    #define  ThreadReturn           return(0)
    #define  JoinThread(t)          pthread_join(t, NULL)

    #define  Flag               sem_t
    #define  MakeFlag(f,n)          sem_init(&f, 0, 0)
    #define  DestroyFlag(f)         sem_destroy(&f)
    #define  RaiseFlag(f)           sem_post(&f)
    #define  WaitForFlag(f)         sem_wait(&f)

    #define  Mutex              pthread_mutex_t
    #define  MakeMutex(m)           pthread_mutex_init(&m, NULL)
    #define  DestroyMutex(m)        pthread_mutex_destroy(&m)
    #define  LockMutex(m)           pthread_mutex_lock(&m)
    #define  UnlockMutex(m)         pthread_mutex_unlock(&m)
    //-----------------------------------
    #endif


    /*************************************************************************/
    /*                                   */
    /*      Constants, macros etc.                   */
    /*                                   */
    /*************************************************************************/


    #define  CUBIST

    #define  MAXN     20        /* max number neighbors allowing for ties */

    #define  Nil       0        /* null pointer */
    #define  false     0
    #define  true      1
    #define  Width     80       /* approx max width of output */

    #define  EXCLUDE   1        /* special attribute status: do not use */
    #define  SKIP      2        /* do not use in models */
    #define  DISCRETE  4        /* ditto: collect values as data read */
    #define  ORDERED   8        /* ditto: ordered discrete values */
    #define  DATEVAL   16       /* ditto: YYYY/MM/DD or YYYY-MM-DD */
    #define  STIMEVAL  32       /* ditto: HH:MM:SS */
    #define  TSTMPVAL  64       /* date time */

    #define  UNKNOWN   1.5777218104420236e-30   /* unlikely value! */
    #define  NA    1

    #define  BrDiscr   1        /* test on discrete attribute */
    #define  BrThresh  2        /* threshold test on continuous attribute */
    #define  BrSubset  3        /* subset test on discrete attribute */

    #define  Plural(n)      ((n) != 1 ? "s" : "")

    #define  AllocZero(N,T)     (T *) Pcalloc(N, sizeof(T))
    #define  Alloc(N,T)     AllocZero(N,T)  /* for safety */
    #define  Realloc(V,N,T)     V = (T *) Prealloc(V, (N)*sizeof(T))

    #define  Max(a,b)               ((a)>(b) ? a : b) 
    #define  Min(a,b)               ((a)<(b) ? a : b) 

    #define  Bit(b)         (1 << (b))
    #define  In(b,s)        ((s[(b) >> 3]) & Bit((b) & 07))
    #define  ClearBits(n,s)     memset(s,0,n)
    #define  CopyBits(n,f,t)    memcpy(t,f,n)
    #define  SetBit(b,s)        (s[(b) >> 3] |= Bit((b) & 07))

    #define  ForEach(v,f,l)     for(v=f ; v<=l ; ++v) 

    #define  StatBit(a,b)       (SpecialStatus[a]&(b))
    #define  Exclude(a)     StatBit(a,EXCLUDE)
    #define  Skip(a)        StatBit(a,EXCLUDE|SKIP)
    #define  Discrete(a)        (MaxAttVal[a] || StatBit(a,DISCRETE))
    #define  Continuous(a)      (! MaxAttVal[a] && ! StatBit(a,DISCRETE))
    #define  Ordered(a)     StatBit(a,ORDERED)
    #define  DateVal(a)     StatBit(a,DATEVAL)
    #define  TimeVal(a)     StatBit(a,STIMEVAL)
    #define  TStampVal(a)       StatBit(a,TSTMPVAL)

    #define  NotApplic(c,a)     (DVal(c,a)==NA)
    #define  NotApplicVal(AV)   (AV._discr_val==NA)

    #define  Space(s)       (s==' ' || s=='\n' || s=='\r' || s=='\t')
    #define  SkipComment        while ( (c = InChar(f)) != '\n' && c != EOF )

    #define  Free(x)        {free(x); x=Nil;}
    #define  FreeUnlessNil(p)   if((p)!=Nil) free(p)

    #define  CheckClose(f)      if(f) {fclose(f); f=Nil;}

    #define  Before(n1,n2)      (n1->Tested < n2->Tested ||\
                     n1->Tested == n2->Tested && n1->Cut < n2->Cut)

    #define  Bound(v,l,h)           ((v) < (l) ? (l) : (v) > (h) ? (h) : (v))


    #define  NOFILE      0
    #define  BADATTNAME  1
    #define  EOFINATT    2
    #define  SINGLEATTVAL    3
    #define  BADATTVAL   4
    #define  BADNUMBER   5
    #define  DUPATTNAME  6
    #define  NOMEM       8
    #define  TOOMANYVALS     9
    #define  BADDISCRETE    10
    #define  NOTARGET   11
    #define  BADTARGET  12
    #define  LONGNAME   13
    #define  HITEOF     14
    #define  MISSNAME   15
    #define  BADDATE    16
    #define  BADTIME    17
    #define  BADTSTMP   18
    #define  UNKNOWNATT 19
    #define  BADDEF1    20
    #define  BADDEF2    21
    #define  BADDEF3    22
    #define  SAMEATT    23
    #define  BADDEF4    24
    #define  MODELFILE  30
    #define  CWTATTERR  31

    #define  Of     stdout
    #define  Goodbye(x) exit(x)
    #define  CharWidth(S)   ((int) strlen(S))



    /*************************************************************************/
    /*                                   */
    /*      Type definitions                     */
    /*                                   */
    /*************************************************************************/


    typedef  unsigned char  Boolean, BranchType, *Set;
    typedef  char       *String;

    typedef  int    CaseNo;     /* data item number */
    typedef  int    CaseCount;  /* count of cases */

     typedef  int   DiscrValue, /* discrete attribute value (0 = ?) */
            Attribute;  /* attribute number, 1..MaxAtt */

    #ifdef USEDOUBLE
    typedef  double ContValue;  /* continuous attribute value */
    #define  PREC   14      /* precision */
    #else
    typedef  float  ContValue;  /* continuous attribute value */
    #define  PREC    7      /* precision */
    #endif

                    /* Attribute values are packed into a union:

                         DVal = (int) discrete value
                         CVal = (float) continuous value
                         SVal = (int) offset in IgnoredVals

                       Missing and non-applicable values are:

                         discrete:
                           not applicable:  DVal = NA
                           missing:     DVal = 0
                         continuous:
                           not applicable:  DVal = NA
                           missing:     CVal = UNKNOWN  */

    typedef  union _attribute_value
         {
            ContValue   _cont_val;
            DiscrValue  _discr_val;
         }
         AttValue, *DataRec;

    #define  CVal(Case,Attribute)   Case[Attribute]._cont_val
    #define  DVal(Case,Attribute)   Case[Attribute]._discr_val
    #define  SVal(Case,Attribute)   Case[Attribute]._discr_val
    #define  Class(Case)        Case[ClassAtt]._cont_val
    #define  PredVal(Case)      Case[MaxAtt+1]._cont_val
    #define  DRef1(Case)        Case[MaxAtt+1]._cont_val
    #define  DRef2(Case)        Case[MaxAtt+2]._cont_val


    typedef  int    RuleNo;         /* rule number */

    typedef  struct _condrec
         {
            BranchType  NodeType;   /* test type */
            Attribute   Tested;     /* attribute tested */
            ContValue   Cut;        /* threshold (if relevant) */
            Set     Subset;     /* subset (if relevant) */
            int     TestValue;  /* specified outcome of test */
         }
         CondRec, *Condition;


    typedef  struct _rulerec
         {
            RuleNo  RNo;        /* rule number */
            int     MNo,        /* member number for committee models */
                Size;       /* number of conditions */
            Condition   *Lhs;       /* conditions themselves */
            double  *Rhs;       /* model given by rule */
            CaseCount   Cover;      /* number of cases covered */
            float   Mean,       /* mean value of cases matching rule */
                LoVal,      /* lowest value in data */
                HiVal,      /* highest value in data */
                LoLim,      /* lower bound on predictions */
                HiLim,      /* upper bound on predictions */
                EstErr;     /* estimated error */
         }
         RuleRec, *CRule;


    typedef  struct _oldrulerec
         {
            RuleNo  RNo;        /* rule number */
            int     Size;       /* number of conditions */
            Condition   *Lhs;       /* conditions themselves */
            double  *Rhs;       /* model given by rule */
            CaseCount   Cover;      /* number of cases covered */
            float   Mean,       /* mean value of cases matching rule */
                LoVal,      /* lowest value in data */
                HiVal,      /* highest value in data */
                LoLim,      /* lower bound on predictions */
                HiLim,      /* upper bound on predictions */
                EstErr;     /* estimated error */
         }
         OldRuleRec;


    typedef struct _rulesetrec
         {
            RuleNo  SNRules;    /* number of rules */
            CRule   *SRule;     /* rules */
         }
         RuleSetRec, *RRuleSet;


    typedef  struct _indexrec   *Index;
    typedef  struct _indexrec
         {
            Attribute   Tested;     /* split attribute for KD-tree */
            ContValue   Cut,        /* threshold for continuous atts */
                MinDRef[2], /* min reference distances */
                MaxDRef[2]; /* max ditto */
            CaseNo  IFp, ILp;   /* first and last item at leaf */
            Index   *SubIndex;  /* subtrees */
         }
         IndexRec;


    typedef  struct _nnrec
         {
            int     BestI[MAXN];    /* numbers of best instances */
            float   BestD[MAXN],    /* distances to best instances */
                *WorstBest, /* points to worst BestD */
                *AttMinD;   /* min attribute distance from case */
         }
         NNEnvRec, *NNEnv;


    typedef  union   _def_val
         {
            String  _s_val;     /* att val for comparison */
            ContValue   _n_val;     /* number for arith */
         }
         DefVal;

    typedef  struct  _def_elt
         {
            short   _op_code;   /* type of element */
            DefVal  _operand;   /* string or numeric value */
         }
         DefElt, *Definition;

    typedef  struct  _elt_rec
         {
            int     Fi,     /* index of first char of element */
                Li;     /* last ditto */
            char    Type;       /* 'B', 'S', or 'N' */
         }
         EltRec;

    #define  DefOp(DE)  DE._op_code
    #define  DefSVal(DE)    DE._operand._s_val
    #define  DefNVal(DE)    DE._operand._n_val

    #define  OP_ATT          0  /* opcodes */
    #define  OP_NUM          1
    #define  OP_STR          2
    #define  OP_MISS         3
    #define  OP_AND         10
    #define  OP_OR          11
    #define  OP_EQ          20
    #define  OP_NE          21
    #define  OP_GT          22
    #define  OP_GE          23
    #define  OP_LT          24
    #define  OP_LE          25
    #define  OP_SEQ         26
    #define  OP_SNE         27
    #define  OP_PLUS        30
    #define  OP_MINUS       31
    #define  OP_UMINUS      32
    #define  OP_MULT        33
    #define  OP_DIV         34
    #define  OP_MOD         35
    #define  OP_POW         36
    #define  OP_SIN         40
    #define  OP_COS         41
    #define  OP_TAN         42
    #define  OP_LOG         43
    #define  OP_EXP         44
    #define  OP_INT         45
    #define  OP_END         99


    /*************************************************************************/
    /*                                   */
    /*      Function prototypes                  */
    /*                                   */
    /*************************************************************************/

    void        PrintResult(int t);
    void        PrepareForSMP(void);
    void        TerminateSMP(void);
    ThreadFn    ProcessCase(int t);
    Boolean     ReadName(FILE *f, String s, int n, char ColonOpt);
    void        GetNames(FILE *Nf);
    void        ExplicitAtt(FILE *Nf);
    int     Which(String Val, String *List, int First, int Last);
    void        FreeNamesData();
    int     InChar(FILE *f);

    void        ImplicitAtt(FILE *Nf);
    void        ReadDefinition(FILE *f);
    void        Append(char c);
    Boolean     Expression();
    Boolean     Conjunct();
    Boolean     SExpression();
    Boolean     AExpression();
    Boolean     Term();
    Boolean     Factor();
    Boolean     Primary();
    Boolean     Atom();
    Boolean     Find(String S);
    int     FindOne(String *Alt);
    Attribute   FindAttName();
    void        DefSyntaxError(String Msg);
    void        DefSemanticsError(int Fi, String Msg, int OpCode);
    void        Dump(char OpCode, ContValue F, String S, int Fi);
    void        DumpOp(char OpCode, int Fi);
    Boolean     UpdateTStack(char OpCode, ContValue F, String S, int Fi);
    AttValue    EvaluateDef(Definition D, DataRec Case);

    void        GetData(FILE *Df, Boolean Train, Boolean AllowUnknownTarget);
    Boolean     ReplaceUnknowns(DataRec Case, Boolean *AttMsg);
    DataRec     GetDataRec(FILE *Df, Boolean Train);
    int     StoreIVal(String S);
    void        CheckValue(DataRec Case, Attribute Att);
    Boolean     OutsideRange(DataRec Case);
    void        FreeCases(DataRec *Case, CaseNo MaxCase);
    void        FreeCase(DataRec DVec);

    void        CheckFile(String Extension, Boolean Write);
    void        ReadFilePrefix(String Extension);
    void        ReadHeader();
    RRuleSet    *GetCommittee(String Extension);
    RRuleSet    InRules();
    CRule       InRule();
    Condition   InCondition();
    void        FreeCttee(RRuleSet *Cttee);
    int     ReadProp(char *Delim);
    String      RemoveQuotes(String S);
    Set     MakeSubset(Attribute Att);
    void        BinRecoverDiscreteNames();
    RRuleSet    BinInRules();
    void        StreamIn(String S, int n);

    void        ReleaseRule(CRule R);
    void        PrintRules(RRuleSet RS, String Msg);
    void        PrintRule(CRule R);
    void        PrintCondition(Condition C);
    Boolean     Satisfies(DataRec CaseDesc, Condition OneCond);

    float       PredictValue(RRuleSet *Cttee, DataRec CaseDesc, float *ErrLim);
    float       RuleSetPrediction(RRuleSet RS, DataRec CaseDesc, float *ErrLim);
    Boolean     Matches(CRule R, DataRec Case);

    void        InitialiseInstances(RRuleSet *Cttee);
    void        CopyInstances(void);
    float       NNEstimate(RRuleSet *Cttee, DataRec Case, NNEnv E, float *ErrLim);
    float       Distance(DataRec Case1, DataRec Case2, float Thresh);
    void        CheckDistance(DataRec Case, CaseNo Saved, NNEnv E);
    void        FindNearestNeighbors(DataRec Case, NNEnv E);
    float       AverageNeighbors(RRuleSet *Cttee, DataRec Case, NNEnv E,
            float *ErrLim);
    void        ShowNearestNeighbors(int Offset, NNEnv E);
    Index       BuildIndex(CaseNo Fp, CaseNo Lp);
    void        ScanIndex(DataRec Case, Index Node, float MinD, NNEnv E);
    void        SwapInstance(CaseNo A, CaseNo B);
    void        FreeIndex(Index Node);
    void        FreeInstances(void);

    char        ProcessOption(int Argc, char *Argv[], char *Options);
    void        *Pmalloc(size_t Bytes);
    void        *Prealloc(void *Present, size_t Bytes);
    void        *Pcalloc(size_t Number, unsigned int Size);
    void        FreeVector(void **V, int First, int Last);

    void        Error(int ErrNo, String S1, String S2);
    FILE        *GetFile(String Extension, String RW);
    int     Denominator(ContValue Val);
    int     FracBase(Attribute Att);
    int     GetInt(String S, int N);
    int     DateToDay(String DS);
    void        DayToDate(int Day, String Date);
    int     TimeToSecs(String TS);
    void        SecsToTime(int Secs, String Time);
    void        SetTSBase(int y);
    int     TStampToMins(String TS);
    void        CValToStr(ContValue CV, Attribute Att, String DS);

    #ifdef WIN32
    double      posrint(double);
    double      rint(double);
    #endif


    /*************************************************************************/
    /*                                   */
    /*      Text strings                         */
    /*                                   */
    /*************************************************************************/


    #define  T_IgnoreNATarget   "*** Ignoring instances with N/A target value\n"
    #define  T_IgnoreBadTarget  "*** Ignoring instances with unknown or N/A"\
                        " target value\n"
    #define  T_NoCases      "*** No instances with known target values\n"

    #define  T_ReplaceUnknowns  "\n    Replacing unknown attribute values:\n"
    #define  T_NoAppVals        "ignoring (no applicable values)"
    #define  T_By           "by"
    #define  T_Rule         "Rule"
    #define  TX_RInfo(c,p,m,l,h,e)  ": [%d cases, mean %.*f, range %.7g to %.7g, "\
                    "est err %.*f]\n\n",c,p,m,l,h,p,e
    #define  T_If           "if"
    #define  T_Then         "then"
    #define  T_ElementOf        "in"
    #define  T_InRange      "in"
    #define  T_IsUnknown        " is unknown\n"
    #define  TX_Line(l,f)       "\n*** line %d of `%s': ", l, f
    #define  E_NOFILE(f,e)      "cannot open file %s%s\n", f, e
    #define  E_BADATTNAME       "`:' or `:=' expected after attribute name"\
                        " `%s'\n"
    #define  E_EOFINATT     "unexpected eof while reading attribute `%s'\n"
    #define  E_SINGLEATTVAL(a,v)    "attribute `%s' has only one value `%s'\n",\
                        a, v
    #define  E_DUPATTNAME       "multiple attributes with name `%s'\n"
    #define  E_CWTATTERR        "case weight attribute must be continuous\n"
    #define  E_BADATTVAL(v,a)   "bad value of `%s' for attribute `%s'\n", v, a
    #define  E_BADNUMBER(a)     "value of `%s' changed to `?'\n", a
    #define  E_NOMEM        "unable to allocate sufficient memory\n"
    #define  E_TOOMANYVALS(a,n) "too many values for attribute `%s'"\
                        " (max %d)\n", a, n
    #define  E_BADDISCRETE      "bad number of discrete values for attribute"\
                        " `%s'\n"
    #define  E_NOTARGET     "target attribute `%s' not found\n"
    #define  E_BADTARGET        "target attribute `%s' is not numeric\n"
    #define  E_LONGNAME     "overlength name: check data file formats\n"
    #define  E_HITEOF       "unexpected end of file\n"
    #define  E_MISSNAME     "missing name or value before `%s'\n"
    #define  E_BADTSTMP(d,a)    "bad timestamp `%s' for attribute `%s'\n", d, a
    #define  E_BADDATE(d,a)     "bad date `%s' for attribute `%s'\n", d, a
    #define  E_BADTIME(d,a)     "bad time `%s' for attribute `%s'\n", d, a
    #define  E_UNKNOWNATT       "unknown attribute name `%s'\n"
    #define  E_BADDEF1(a,s,x)   "in definition of attribute `%s':\n"\
                        "\tat `%.12s': expect %s\n", a, s, x
    #define  E_BADDEF2(a,s,x)   "in definition of attribute `%s':\n"\
                        "\t`%s': %s\n", a, s, x
    #define  E_SAMEATT(a,b)     "attribute `%s' is identical to attribute"\
                        " `%s'\n", a, b
    #define  E_BADDEF3      "cannot define target attribute `%s'\n"
    #define  E_BADDEF4      "target attribute appears in definition"\
                        " of attribute `%s':\n"
    #define  EX_MODELFILE(f)    "file %s incompatible with .names file\n", f
    #define  E_MFATT        "undefined or excluded attribute"
    #define  E_MFATTVAL     "undefined attribute value"
    #define  E_MFEOF        "unexpected eof"
    #define  T_ErrorLimit       "Error limit exceeded\n"

    #ifdef _CONSOLE
    #define  finite(x)  _finite(x)
    #endif
```

**global.c**

```
Attribute   ClassAtt=0, /* attribute to use as class */
            LabelAtt=0, /* attribute containing case label */
            CWtAtt=0;   /* attribute containing case weight */

    int     MaxAtt,     /* max att number */
            MaxDiscrVal=3,  /* max discrete values for any att */
            Precision=2,    /* decimal places for target */
            MaxLabel=0, /* max characters in case label */
            LineNo=0,   /* input line number */
            ErrMsgs=0,  /* errors found */
            AttExIn,    /* attribute exclusions/inclusions */
            TSBase=0,   /* base day for time stamps */
            Delimiter,  /* character at end of name */
            NCPU=1;     /* number of CPUs */

    float       ErrReduction=1; /* effect of committee model */

    int CaseNo,     MaxCase=-1; /* max data item number */

    DataRec *Case;      /* data items */

    DiscrValue  *MaxAttVal, /* number of values for each att */
            *Modal;     /* most frequent value for discr att */

    char        *SpecialStatus; /* special att treatment */

    Definition  *AttDef;    /* definitions of implicit atts */

    String      Target,     /* name of dependent att */
            *AttName,   /* att names */
            **AttValName;   /* att value names */

    char        *IgnoredVals=0; /* values of labels and ignored atts */
    int     IValsSize=0,    /* size of above */
            IValsOffset=0;  /* index of first free char */

    String      FileStem="undefined";
    char        Fn[512];    /* file name */

    FILE        *Mf=0;      /* file for reading models */

    ContValue   *AttMean=Nil,   /* means of att values */
            *AttSD=Nil, /* std dev ditto */
            *AttMaxVal=Nil, /* max value in training data */
            *AttMinVal=Nil, /* min value ditto */
            Ceiling=1E38,   /* max allowable global prediction */
            Floor=-1E38;    /* min allowable global prediction */

    int     *AttPrec=Nil;   /* Attribute precision  */

    DataRec     *Instance=Nil,  /* training cases */
            Ref[2];     /* reference point */
    Index       KDTree=Nil; /* index for searching training cases */
    CaseNo      MaxInstance=-1; /* highest instance */
    float       *RSPredVal=Nil, /* tabulated RS predictions */
            *RSErrLim=Nil;  /* tabulated RS error limits */
    NNEnvRec    GNNEnv;     /* global NN environment */

    unsigned char   *Tested;    /* used in BuildIndex */
    CaseCount   *ValFreq;   /* used in BuildIndex */

    RRuleSet    *CubistModel;   /* from .model file */

    Boolean     USEINSTANCES;
    float       EXTRAP=0.05,    /* allowed extrapolation from models */
            SAMPLE=0.0, /* sample training proportion  */
            MAXD,       /* max distance for close neighbors */
            GlobalMean=0,   /* global mean on training data */
            GlobalErrLim;   /* estimated global error limit */
    int     MEMBERS=1,  /* models in committee */
            NN=5,       /* nearest neighbors to use */
            KRInit;
```

Comment: Respect for the (over?)use of the expression separator operator. Have an upvote for that. This code is above my pay grade.

Comment: Are the type-alias definitions in a header file, and the variable definitions in a source file? Are you including the correct header file in the source file? Can you perhaps try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: Also be careful when creating type-aliases as pointer (like your `DataRec`). You define `Case` to be a pointer to a pointer to the `_attribute_value` union. I.e. your definition is the same as doing `union _attribute_value **Case;`. Is that your meaning?

Comment: Are you including the header file in the compilation unit giving the errors?  Where exactly does it say these errors are?  Is it in the header file or in the compilation unit.

Comment: You have to show the code where the errors are generated and tell us which line the error is on. Also is the fragment in your question in a header file which is included (or perhaps not included) in the file with the errors?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes you are right type-alias are in a definition and variable definition in a source file and i included the the header file correctly.

Comment: @cup  the errors are in the compilation unit.

Comment: @jeremyP The errors appear in the source file where the variable is defined for example in the first ERROR message >>Unknown type name  'Attribute' the erroneous line is the line in the definition where the variable Attribute is located.                                                                                Attribute   ClassAtt=0, /* attribute to use as class */
                            LabelAtt=0, /* attribute containing case label */
                            CWtAtt=0;   /* attribute containing case weight */

Comment: If the type is undefined when you use it to declare a variable, you haven't `#include`ed the header.

Comment: I compiled the posted code (ubuntu linux, gcc)  the result is three error messages: `error: unknown type name 'ContValue'` and two instances of   `error: unknown type name 'String'`   Please post the associated header file.